# cs50 reflect code is failing. values are not in there right place

Tags: c, cs50, swap

I cant find a way to fix these two errors despite that the pic reflects correctly when i test it by myself.
this is the error

```
testing with sample 1x3 image
first row: (255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255)
running ./testing 2 1...
checking for output "0 0 255\n0 255 0\n255 0 0\n"...
```

#### Expected Output:

```
0 0 255
0 255 0
255 0 0
```

#### Actual Output:

```
0 0 0
0 0 255
0 255 0
```

I noticed that there is a value from the second row in the first row and a value from the third row in the second row.
this is the code:

```
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    //this is where the reflected image gonna be
    RGBTRIPLE reflected[height][width];
    for (int h = 0 ; h < height ; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0 ; w < width ; w++)
        {
            reflected[h][w] = image[h][width - w];
        }
    }
    //copying from the reflected to the image
    for (int h = 0 ; h < height ; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0 ; w < width ; w++)
        {
           image[h][w] = reflected[h][w];
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

the problem is solved but now I have another problem in 3x3 image where the first row of each column is zeros

#### Expected Output:

```
255 0 0
255 0 0
255 0 0
0 255 0
0 255 0
0 255 0
0 0 255
0 0 255
0 0 255
```

#### Actual Output:

```
0 0 0
255 0 0
255 0 0
0 0 0
0 255 0
0 255 0
0 0 0
0 0 255
0 0 255
```

tried writing the code in different ways but I ended up with the same bug.

Comment: Your function produces no _Actual Output_.

Comment: A minimal reproducible example needs a main(), the input and the output. Otherwise we cannot run your function, unless we guess how you get input, how you produce output.

Comment: Please be aware that SO has a one question per post policy. Your question shall be about one problem that can be addresses in answers. Moving the target to something different is not how SO works. It makes existing answers less useful as they do not address the new issue. Also your code is still the code with the old problem (And also should not be changed as this would also make all existing answers useless). If you have a different problem, please post a new question. This time already include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) directly in the question. `

Comment: Providing a MCVE means you must create a `main` function that provides test data, calls your function and handles the output. Just the same as you would need to test your code yourself anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must always check your ranges: `image[r][c]` assumes that `0 <= r < height` and that `0 <= c < width`.

Now consider your `image[h][width-w]`. What is the range of `width-w`? When `w = 0 => width-w = width`. Out of range (and UB).

You just fix it with `image[h][width-1 - w]`.

Comment: thank you, but there is still an error in the first row of each column
Expected Output:

255 0 0

255 0 0

255 0 0

0 255 0

0 255 0

0 255 0

0 0 255

0 0 255

0 0 255

Actual Output:

0 0 0

255 0 0
255 0 0
0 0 0
0 255 0
0 255 0
0 0 0
0 0 255
0 0 255

Comment: You realize that a bunch of numbers is not an image without the dimensions? This is why you should provide a [mcve] in your question. The function looks fine with the suggested correction, but if you want further help, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75924807/edit) your question including libraries, input, output and `main()`.

Comment: can you chick the question again I have added more details